# MONGODB Mongoimport possible speed up?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, csv, mongoimport

I have a 2 GB CSV file with 9 M records that I import into MongoDB using the native mongoimport tool. It imports the CSV at a rate of 8K per second. The overall time taken is 10 minutes. The speed of import is quite reasonable, but it seems to be much slower than the MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE version(takes only 2 minutes to insert all of the records into the database). While this is acceptable (MongoDB is built for JSON type objects and speed ups are generally in querying and not in inserting), I would like to know if there is some way that I can speed up the number of inserts per second done in MongoDB mongoimport?
I have only one computer with 8 GB RAM and 4 cores.
Thanks.

Comment: Put it on a second disk, make sure there aren't any indexes... Turn off journaling... If it isn't hammering disk and CPU, you might be able to write a bit of code to read from the file and insert it more quickly. Or, just take a break, and wait it out. :)

Comment: Ok I thought the native import tool would be faster than "a piece of code to run through the file and perform batch inserts". Is this a misconception on my side ?

Comment: Is the computer really busy already? Maybe it's as good as your computer will do.

Comment: mongoimport has to serialize all the json records into bson - so it's not a "native" tool in the sense that it's not loading native to MongoDB format.

Comment: @WiredPrairie - I guess that's true. I might just have to live with it. I just wanted to know if there was some way to tweak the performance. I totally understand if that's the best that can be done.

Comment: @Asya - Yes you are right, maybe that's why it's not as fast as the MySQL LOAD INTO statement for the CSV file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the majority of time is likely spent serializing JSON objects into BSON (native MongoDB format) you will likely get faster import if you can split up your file and have several parallel jobs each running mongoimport with a separate file.