# mongoimport very very slow for large json file

Tags: mongoimport

I have a large json file (350GB) and I am trying to import it in MongoDB collection using mongoimport.The mongoimport is very very slow and I am not sure how many days it will take.

Can any one please suggest the best way to load this json file to mongodb collection. I have enough disk space to load this json file.

Answer (score 3):

I came across similar situation. I used `mongorestore` instead of `mongoimport` but the idea is the same. `iotop` shows that the restore process had an IO rate of about 1M/s which is pretty low. As [other post here suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118609/mongodb-mongoimport-possible-speed-up), the low performance is probably due to the json to bson serialization. So I ended splitting up the exported json file into different chunks with the following command

```
mongodump --host < host > --port < port > --username < user > --password < pwd > --authenticateionDatabase admin --db < db > --collection < coll > --query "{DayOfWeek:"Monday"}" --out "SomeDir-Monday" &

mongodump --host < host > --port < port > --username < user > --password < pwd > --authenticateionDatabase admin --db < db > --collection < coll > --query "{DayOfWeek:"Tuesday"}" --out "SomeDir-Tuesday" &

...
```

then I ended up having 7 chunks. 
Finally import these chunks in parallel using mongorestore with following command.

```
mongorestore --host < host > --port < port > --username < user > --password < pwd > --authenticateionDatabase admin --db < db > --collection < coll > PATH_TO_MONDAY.json &

mongorestore --host < host > --port < port > --username < user > --password < pwd > --authenticateionDatabase admin --db < db > --collection < coll > PATH_TO_TUESDAY.json &
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the update.

I will use this approach while creating the dump again. 

I was using mongoimport as I had json file and not bson file for my collection. That collection doesn't exists now,so I cannot create the dump again using the chunks approach.I have to find a way to split the big json file and load it.

Thanks.

Comment: considering the mongodump command you have given query params with on basics of some key value but I have a large db with something like a key but not a general value for that. How can I make a chunk in that case?

Comment: I am going through kind of a same situation. Just wanted to confirm , if I cancel the import script will the db hold data upto that timeframe ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using mongodb > 3.0.0 you can use the `--numInsertionWorkers` on the *mongoimport* command
Set this to the number of CPUs you have in order to speedup the import.
[ref.](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/)

Answer (score 0):

Use a Studio3T-mongoChef GUI client where importing JSON,dump etc. are simple yet faster.

Comment: Doesn't work if mongo is running in Kubernetes and it is documented that you cannot connect to mongo from the outside.